# Tag Request: TAILS

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I am unable to add this tag For the OS (see image below).  It's an acronym for the Linux distro known as "The Amnesic Incognito Live System". This is an [example question](https://superuser.com/questions/746170/which-version-of-openoffice-does-tails-have) referring to TAILS and the full version of the name is too long for a tag. How should I proceed?

[image]

Comment: Is there an actual need for that tag? Could you maybe provide a few questions where it's used? There are only two posts mentioning 'amnesic' (and searching for "tails" results in a lot of false positive results…). Also, note that with more than 300 reputation, you can create new tags -- if you're confident that it's useful, go for it.

Comment: @DanielBeck, actually despite my rep it wouldn't let me because 'tail' was a tag already and it thought I meant the plural of that, which I don't.  But edited to give an example.

Comment: @Kev ah, yes now your question is much more clear than before because of that comment, you are suggesting a tag addition because the system is declining your attempts to define it.

Comment: By accepting an answer you're marking this question as answered. I don't see the TAILS tag as having been created and the question isn't `status-completed` - have you decided that this tag wouldn't be useful? We have about 5 example questions that could benefit from the tag and I think this tag request is a good one. @DanielBeck any advice on getting this tag created?

Comment: @Raystafarian, I meant to accept the answer of 'we ought to make a tag.'  I've unaccepted based on your interpretation.  Yes, anybody who could advise how to get the tag created, please do...

Comment: [There you go](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tails). Please follow up with tagging appropriate questions and writing a tag wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TAILS](https://tails.boum.org/) is a distribution made for anonymity and security. One that forces all traffic to go through TOR. This is majorly different to most other Linux distributions. It is unique, and questions related to it are likely to be more specialized.

I mean, on-top of the tags we have for more popular distributions like [ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu), and [debian](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/debian), we also have tags for lesser known distributions like [solaris](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/solaris) and [netbsd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/netbsd). I believe TAILS deserves it's own tag as much as any other distribution does.

According to [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com/), in the last 12 months, TAILS has the 35th most "hits per day" (on average) of the distributions on their site. It is two distributions below [pc-bsd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pc-bsd) (which as you can see, has it's own tag), and six below [redhat](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/redhat). This shows that it is fairly well-known distribution, and therefore has the potential for people to benefit from questions asked about it here.

To further prove my point, below are a few examples of previous questions that should be grouped under the TAILS tag:

- [Tails "clone" LiveUSB wont boot](https://superuser.com/questions/688180/tails-clone-liveusb-wont-boot)
- [Configuring persistent storage on Tails linux](https://superuser.com/questions/669547/configuring-persistent-storage-on-tails-linux)
- [How to make Tails Live USB Bootable](https://superuser.com/questions/646362/how-to-make-tails-live-usb-bootable)
- https://superuser.com/questions/685729/tails-debianconnecting-to-wifi

And finally, I also believe that if there were to be a tag for TAILS, more people would ask (and therefore answer) questions regarding it (benefiting everyone in their community).